# Mongo find out connection read preference

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a node.js app using Mongoose (v5.11.17) drivers. Before I used standalone db, but recently for reliability concerns the app was migrated to replicas set (of 3). There is a code that saves some object `a` in the db, and then could be any number of calls reading object `a`. Since migrating to the replica set some times reading can return as not found, that has never happened with the standalone db. My guess is the read preferences are not right somehow and the read goes to a non-primary db (or may be the write went to non-primary). Can I find out from the connection in mongo shell and query its read preference?

Comment: You cannot write into non-primary. For the read preference you have to check the defaults: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-defaults/#read-concern But it can be overwritten at many places.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Thanks. Do you think is there a chance to check at least the obvious suspects: connection, database, by using some kind of query in mongo shell.

Comment: The default is `local`, i.e. no guarantee that the data has been written to a majority of the replica. Change it where needed.

Comment: But this is not the same like read preference, right? So I think I need to find out the read prefernce.

Comment: As far as I know this is only set in connection string: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-preference/index.html